# Delay of an AutoScaling action triggered by a CloudWatch Alarm

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, autoscaling

I have an EC2 autoscaling group, with scale-out triggered by a step policy. The policy threshold seems to be detected correctly, but the action is delayed by 4-5 minutes. It seems to be reflected in the alarm logs:

```
"newState": {
    "stateValue": "ALARM",
    "stateReason": "Threshold Crossed: 1 out of the last 1 datapoints [548.0 (03/01/19 20:27:00)] was greater than the threshold (160.0) (minimum 1 datapoint for OK -> ALARM transition).",
    "stateReasonData": {
      "version": "1.0",
      "queryDate": "2019-01-03T20:31:31.936+0000",
      "startDate": "2019-01-03T20:27:00.000+0000",
      "statistic": "Sum",
      "period": 60,
      "recentDatapoints": [
        548
      ],
      "threshold": 160
    }
  }
```

And the ASG activity log:

```
At 2019-01-03T20:31:31Z a monitor alarm scale-out-alarm in state ALARM triggered policy scale-out-policy changing the desired capacity from 1 to 4. At 2019-01-03T20:32:01Z an instance was started in response to a difference between desired and actual capacity, increasing the capacity from 1 to 4.
```

Notice that the threshold was crossed at 20:27:00, while the action was taken at 20:31:31. These seem to correlate with the "startDate" and the "queryDate" in the log, although I haven't found any documentation of these properties.

Is this just a matter of random delays in CloudWatch, or there is another reason for such a delay?

The ASG hasn't been scaled for a long period of time before that, so it doesn't seem to be related to warmup/cooldown.

Both EvaluationPeriods and DatapointsToAlarm are 1.

After some further investigation, it seems that the delay is much larger when the alarm is based on ALB's RequestCount metrics than it is for EC2 CPUUtilization. Does it make sense?